# RecyclerView custom CursorAdapter - Setting values to Views in onBindViewHolder and parsing them in the ViewHolder Constructor?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-recyclerview

In my onBindViewHolder method i read values out of my Database and set the Views accordingly. In my ViewHolder Constructor i want to set an onClickListener on itemView and access the same Database values there. Right now i am parsing them out of the Views i set in onBindViewHolder. This doesn't seem the best way to do this.
How would i approach this properly? Should i query the Database in the ViewHolder or simply save the values in a member variable of my Adapter?

```
public class GroceryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceryAdapter.GroceryViewHolder> {
private Context mContext;
private Cursor mCursor;

private OnItemClickListener mListener;

public GroceryAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    mContext = context;
    mCursor = cursor;
}

public class GroceryViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView nameText;
    public TextView countText;

    public GroceryViewHolder(final View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        nameText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name_text);
        countText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.amount_text);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mListener.onItemClick((long) itemView.getTag(),
                        Integer.parseInt(countText.getText().toString()), nameText.getText().toString());
            }
        });
    }
}

@Override
public GroceryViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grocery_item, parent, false);
    return new GroceryViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(GroceryViewHolder holder, int position) {
    if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
        return;
    }
    String name = mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_NAME));
    int amount = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry.COLUMN_AMOUNT));
    long id = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(GroceryContract.GroceryEntry._ID));

    holder.nameText.setText(name);
    holder.countText.setText(String.valueOf(amount));
    holder.itemView.setTag(id);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return mCursor.getCount();
}

public void swapCursor(Cursor newCursor) {
    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.close();
    }

    mCursor = newCursor;

    if (newCursor != null) {
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public interface OnItemClickListener{
    void onItemClick(long id, int amount, String name);
}

public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}
```

}

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/Shywim/127f207e7248fe48400b) adapter as a base class: you will avoid a lot of boilerplate code and also it implements `getItemId` so you dont have to use setTag/getTag stuff

Comment: Thank you, i will use that next time. But right now i have to get the one up there working.